# I couldn't import the tables from my sql server to hive through sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, sqoop

When I pass the command:

$sqoop create-hive-table --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.100.0.18:1433;username=cloud;password=cloud123;database=hadoop' --table cluster

Some errors and warnings appear and at the end it says,
Failed to start database '/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db', see the next exception for details [again a list of import errors displayed]

Finally it says hive exited with satus 9

What is the problem here? I am new to sqoop and hive. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be

sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.100.0.18:1433/hadoop' --username cloud --password cloud123 --table cluster --hive-import

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to check if you have write permissions to the specified directory and if a directory named metastore_db is being created

Answer (score 0):

This message is usually shown when you're running Sqoop with default Hive configuration. Hive will by default use derby datastore which is usable only in very basic test use cases. I would recommend to reconfigure your hive instance to use some other relation database as a datastore back end (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all wrong.  Syntax is $sqoop tool-name [tool-arguments]

> $sqoop **import** --create-hive-table --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.100.0.18:1433/hadoop' --username cloud --password cloud123 --table cluster

Answer (score 0):

Pasting a sample call of hive import using sqoop. This might help you to correct your syntax further. Remember that essentially you need to give minimum the below command to make it work.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/RAWDATA --table geolocation --username root --password hadoop  --hive-import  --create-hive-table --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --m 1 --delete-target-dir
```

1. **--connect**, in this the part which reads /**RAWDATA** is the database name from  your mysql instance which contains the geolocation table. You can execute 'show databases' and 'show tables' command in mysql to check for your databases and tables.
2. **--delete-target-dir** option is used for safety. It will ensure sqoop delete the tmp dir it creates to write the file before moving it into hive. This will avoid unnecessary errors of directory already exists, in case you retry the command.
3. **--create-hive-table**  is required only if you did not create the target table in hive already. If your previous runs of sqoop command created the table already, then you can ignore this option completely. Check your hive database for existence of target hive table.
4. **--driver** is a mandatory part of the command to perform any database connection.Make sure you either find the right path to the driver library or try googling for options. You can try first the one pasted above to see if it does the trick. You can revert to this forum for help.
5. remember we did not mention which database in hive the table will be created therefore it will be in default database of hive. I am not giving that option since you are just about starting in sqoop.